# How to grab website certificates?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, keystore

I need to obtain all certificates that build a chain from the endpoint certificate the whole way up to the Root CA so i can import them to the keystore and then use them in my application.

How can i do this in Windows (can't find this option in browsers)?

Comment: You can also do this programmatically. The program `InstallCert` can be found here: http://blogs.sun.com/andreas/entry/no_more_unable_to_find. You might use that as a starting point.

Comment: Oracle seem to have deleted the blog post suggested by @musikk

Comment: @James: If you search for the title, you'll find that it is mirrored a few times. And there is always archive.org. Still it's a bummer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you are using IE, rather than go through it for every browser.

When you access the website, there should be a little lock indicating the connection is secure (right of the address bar in IE 8, forget where for the other versions).

It'll bring up a window that says **Website Identification**, click **view certificates**

This'll bring up the site's certificate, which you can save.  There'll also be a tab that indicates **Certification Path**.  Click that, and you'll see the intermediate chain.  Click each and save them to disk, then you can import them as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments left on the OP question, I found the original article in the Oracle Blog archives:

https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification

Though you will not be able to download the InstallCert.java file linked in the article, you will find it on a mirrored site:

http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target